# Update UI of another activity based on results in Main activity

Tags: android

Have created two classes 1. MainActivity.java 2. Chat_user.java. Chat_user class list all contacts with whom chat is going on and hold the recent chat message. Main Activity has Asynch Task created for getting chat message from other user. My query is as follows :-

On getting new message through Asynch task in MainActivity.java class
•   Will it be possible to add one row item in list view (created through Recycle view) created by Chat_user class if contact is not present in the list?
•   Will it be possible to add text value(number of chat msg received after last checking) in existing row item if contact is present in the list view created by Chat_user class?

If yes, please advise how this can be achieved?

Thnx in advance for your help…….

Comment: Use BroadcastReceiver, send a broadcast when there is a new message and then update the list in onReceive()

Comment: tell about what you are doing now for this problem . any approach you have ? do you have a database for this ? any code or more information please.

Comment: Hi Sagar,

Thnx for the reply. We have SQlite database which holds chat msg and diplays as list view in Chat_user class. Where I am getting stuck is how to update this list (in Chat_user class) based on new message received through Asynch task (Main Activity class). So far googled out to find if we can able to update list through notify adapter but could not able to figure out.

Thnx in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So, why you are not using that particular message number or name from where it came.

i'm not able to comment due to low repo.

Comment: I have created token for making it unique. the problem i am facing is how to update list view of Chat_user class from Main Activity class with that particular token as this token will be integer and will change will every list item.

Comment: To update listview of chat_user class, You can broadcast the content in chat_user class from mainActivity. so the new text value will broadcast in cha_user class and then you can update your listview.

Answer (score 0):

You need a database to store the message history. If MainActivity receive new message through AsyncTask, you must store the message to your database. And when Chat_user Activity opened, you just load the message from your database. About Text value(number of chat msg received after last checking), you can make a field on your database that store a counter. When new message arrived, the counter will be incremented, and when Chat_user Activity opened, the counter will be reseted to 0. If you need a good database for Android, i suggest you use GreenDAO.

Update from your comment description:
So to update your Chat_user directly from your MainActivity, you must keep the reference of Chat_user that you created.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //keep the reference, so you can use it to update directly
    private Chat_user chatUserFragment = new Chat_user();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        //you must create a method to update your message list in your Chat_user, and call the method from your AsyncTask when a new message come
        chatUserFragment.updateMessage(aNewMessage);
    }
}
```

Example of the adapter:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Message> data;

    public MessageAdapter(){
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<Message> data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Database is already there. Chat_user class fetch data from SQLite database and display as list view. My query is to update this list view as soon as new msg recieved through Asynch task created in Main Activity class

Comment: is Chat_user an Activity?

Comment: Yes this is an activity.

Comment: And why do you think that your 2 activities active at the same time?

Comment: As far as i know, only 1 activity active on the foreground. I suppose that your MainActivity is on the first stack, and when you call Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Chat_user.class);
        startActivity(intent); your MainActivity will be on background. Is your MainActivity has AsyncTask that active to receive message in this state?

Comment: Hendra thnx for reply and sorry for replying late.Yes you are right.Actually we have utilized Fragment in main activity and each tab has one activity associated to it. On launching app, Chat tab (Chat_user) comes in picture. were we displayed list view. Async task is inside Main Activity class. Thnx

Comment: So, you mean Chat_user is a Fragment inside MainActivity right? If so, i don't think any problem to update your Chat_user fragment. You just need to save the instance of your Chat_user fragment and make a method on that Chat_user fragment to update the list. When your MainActivity receive new message, you just need to pass the new message to the method that you created above using the instance that you keep

Comment: Yes Hendra, you got it right. When i recieve new message on main activity, I need to check if it from existing contact or from new contact. If it is from existing contact, need to update same list row. How can i able to identify existing row? can u provide some code of doing it as i have never assign integer id to any text view and picked them through findViewById method. Googled but could not get it correctly.  Thnx in advance

Comment: @Subhash didn't you use Adapter to show the content of your ListView? You just need to update the data of your adapter and call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: About how you can identify if it from existing contact or new contact, you must specify the id of contact to be included as the data's field

Comment: Hi Hendra thnx for reply....I have assign integer token. the token will be unique number assign for every chat. Want to use this token as id of Textview. how can i do this?under main activity i would like to call this textview through findviewbyid() method. this help me to identify which row to be updated. Thnx in advance

Comment: As i mention, you don't need to update the specific TextView, since adapter will use re-useable style with view holder. You just need to update the data, and call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Thnx a lot for the answers you have provided. Will check and come back. Dont understand why my question get downvote. new to Stakoverflow community. Let me know how can i contribute to ur ratings as your answers really add value to my work. Thanx again mate